# SDL Web | getComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority issue in Content Service

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

We have content service installed as Standalone service. We have our custom service that invokes getComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority of content service to get component xml. 
But getComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority is returning null almost every time (rarely it's returning data though)

I enable Debug logs for content service and I feel that it's internally stuck at getComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority, so our custom service response times out and gets null.
In Content Service logs I see:Calling method: 'getComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority' with parameters: [7.0, 66821.0]
And nothing after that each time the method is invoked.
would appreciate any hints why it would behave so. Thanks,